# Filter Word mail merge data using current date

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I am trying to semi-automate an email merge in Word. Excel is the source. Under filtering, I want the "Notice Date" column in the spreadsheet to equal whatever the current date is. Can I do that so we don't have to manually type the current date in the "compare to" field every day on the Filter and Sort dialog.

Comment: The formula to show the current date is =TODAY()

Comment: It gives an error when I put that in the Compare to field. Maybe it only takes constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in the filtering dialog box, but there are two options:
 a. Use a nested field like this at the beginning of your mail merge main document:
[[edited to show <> rather than =]]
{ SKIPIF { MERGEFIELD thedatefieldname \@YYYYMMDD } <> { DATE \@YYYYMMDD } } 
 b. Use VBA to make the connection and provide a bit of SQL that does the comparison,

Two notes on (a) - I am not sure it will work with an emial merge as Word could generate blank emails. Microsoft has been saying for years that filtering should be used instead of SKIPIF but it always sounds to me as if the people who say that do not realise that the two methods do significantly different things.

For (b), you need something like the following for a default type (OLE DB) connection:

```
Sub connectToMMDS() 
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:="the full path name of your Excel workbook", _ SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Sheetname$] WHERE [datecolumn] = date()" 
End Sub
```

Sheetname is the name of the sheet (i.e. if it's Sheet1, use [Sheet1$]). If it's a named range like myrange, use [myrange] and don't add the $.

Comment: A) Didn't seem to work. I got no records for email or creating docs. B) Didn't work either. For B) how does it know that that is the connection to use?  When I open the doc it still shows SQL for the original connection to Excel with no WHERE clause.

Comment: For a, you probably need <> rather than = - I will try to edit my post
For b, you will probably need to remove the existing connection before Word will remember the new one. e.g., open your existing Mail Merge Main Document, get through any data source dialog, change the Main document type to be Normal Document (not a mail merge document), save/close, re-open, run the VBA, save, close and re-open.

Comment: For a) I put at at the top of my document. It appears like regular text..not sure if that is right. Even if I change it to:{ SKIPIF {  1 <> 1  } } , I get no emails (or docs if I try that).

Comment: i figured out I have to do it through insert field. I put in: SKIPIF  { MERGEFIELD Notice_Date \@YYYYMMDD } <> { DATE \@YYYYMMDD }. It gives an error during the merge about too many picture switches.

Comment: /Every/ pair of {} has to be the "special field code braces" that you can insert using ctrl-F9.

Comment: I figured out part of my problem. I was inserting multiple fields and couldn't see them (I didn't know about Toggle Codes). I cleaned that up. I think I have the right thing there, but I still get too many picture switches defined.  I have only 1 per expression:  {SKIPIF { MERGEFIELD Notice_Date \@ "yyyyMMdd" } <> { DATE \@ "yyyyMMdd" }}

Comment: If I remove the format on the first date, it doesn't return an error. Of course, it doesn't work because the dates will never match.

Comment: I still think you aren't inserting the correct type of {}. DO this: use ctrl-F9 to give you {  }. Then click between those {  } and use ctrl-F9 to give you { {  } }. Then click between the two } } and use ctrl-F9 to give you { {  }{  } }. If Word hides the fields, use Alt-F9 to show them again. Then type the other pieces of text ( SKIPIF etc.) in the appropriate gaps. Make sure there is a space either side of the <>. Then select the whole lot and press F9 to update the fields, just in case.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't realize I had to do the CTRL-f9 for all the brackets.  It is working now.  Thanks for all the help. I am a programmer and got pulled into this thing and don't use Word other than for typing documents.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to do a preview using the SKIPIF? It seems like the preview still shows each record.

Comment: I don't know a way to change the way that works. If the "use VBA to make the connection" option is available to you, it's worth at least trying.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the Excel spreadsheet, put this on one of the columns.

```
=IF(Y2=TODAY(),1,0)
```